# Calculating the Fisher Information of bivariate normal

Tags: estimation, information-theory, mixture-distribution, fisher-information

I'm lost. If I estimated the a Gaussian mixture model, with a shared diagonal covariance, will the Fisher information of the means be $\Sigma^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @BlainWaan The EM algoriithm is a method for finding the maximum likelihood estimate when the the simple method of setting partial derivatives to zero cannot be applied. So it is wrong to say that you are using EM instead of maximum likelihood. McLachlan's books on mixture models and the EM algorithm are very helpful in this regard.  By the way, what does your comment have to do with the OPs question?